# Grab banner of different ports with python

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7, network-programming, port

I'm working on a script that grabs the banner from common ports of a host. I'm using sockets to make the connection but I'm facing some issues. Here is the code:

```
    try:
    connsocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    connsocket.settimeout( 5 )
    connsocket.connect((ip, port))
    connsocket.send("HEAD / HTTP/1.0")
    results = connsocket.recv(400)
    connsocket.close()
    return str(results)

except:
    print '[ERROR]Failed to connect or Connection timed out'
```

The are two major issues:

- First time I run the script to a host all the banners are retrieved correctly except port 80 which exits with the timeout
- The second problem is that when I relaunch the script to the same host there is no response from any port.

I suspect that the second issue is due to the connection is still open and the script fails retying to connect. With the first issue I have no idea why it's not working.

Any idea?
Regards.

Comment: Remove try ... except ...  and see what's going on.

Comment: @falsetru It just exits due to the timeout, If I remove the timeout it just do nothing and try to connect forever. This only happens with port 80 (Through telnet or browser it connects)

Comment: connsocket.send("HEAD / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"); How about this?

Comment: @falsetru That seems to be working now. I will test it in different situations and post the results. Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22747732/538284