# Banner grabbing HTTP

Tags: python, banner

I'm trying to implement HTTP banner grabbing.
I wrote this:

```
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.settimeout(2)
s.connect((ip_address,80)) 

byte = str.encode("Server:\r\n")
s.send(byte)
banner = s.recv(1024)
print(banner)
```

It should print `Bad request` massage with further information about the server but instead it prints me the HTML of the browser.

Comment: related: [How do you send a HEAD HTTP request in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/107405/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a http web server receive a `HTTP` method from your `client` for example `Server:\r\n` and that is meaningless for web server, it may return a response that have both header and content.

[4xx Client Error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error):

> The 4xx class of status code is intended for cases in which the client
>   seems to have errored. Except when responding to a HEAD request, the
>   server should include an entity containing an explanation of the error
>   situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent condition. These
>   status codes are applicable to any request method. User agents should
>   display any included entity to the user.

So if you want only header section for [grabbing banner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banner_grabbing), send a HTTP `HEAD` request.

Here is an example:

```
import socket


def http_banner_grabber(ip, port=80, method="HEAD",
                        timeout=60, http_type="HTTP/1.1"):
    assert method in ['GET', 'HEAD']
    # @see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/246859/538284
    assert http_type in ['HTTP/0.9', "HTTP/1.0", 'HTTP/1.1']
    cr_lf = '\r\n'
    lf_lf = '\n\n'
    crlf_crlf = cr_lf + cr_lf
    res_sep = ''
    # how much read from buffer socket in every read
    rec_chunk = 4096
    s = socket.socket()
    s.settimeout(timeout)
    s.connect((ip, port))
    # the req_data is like 'HEAD HTTP/1.1 \r\n'
    req_data = "{} / {}{}".format(method, http_type, cr_lf)
    # if is a HTTP 1.1 protocol request,
    if http_type == "HTTP/1.1":
        # then we need to send Host header (we send ip instead of host here!)
        # adding host header to req_data like 'Host: google.com:80\r\n'
        req_data += 'Host: {}:{}{}'.format(ip, port, cr_lf)
        # set connection header to close for HTTP 1.1
        # adding connection header to req_data like 'Connection: close\r\n'
        req_data += "Connection: close{}".format(cr_lf)
    # headers join together with `\r\n` and ends with `\r\n\r\n`
    # adding '\r\n' to end of req_data
    req_data += cr_lf
    # the s.send() method may send only partial content. 
    # so we used s.sendall()
    s.sendall(req_data.encode())
    res_data = b''
    # default maximum header response is different in web servers: 4k, 8k, 16k
    # @see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8623061/538284
    # the s.recv(n) method may receive less than n bytes, 
    # so we used it in while.
    while 1:
        try:
            chunk = s.recv(rec_chunk)
            res_data += chunk
        except socket.error:
            break
        if not chunk:
            break
    if res_data:
        # decode `res_data` after reading all content of data buffer
        res_data = res_data.decode()
    else:
        return '', ''
    # detect header and body separated that is '\r\n\r\n' or '\n\n'
    if crlf_crlf in res_data:
        res_sep = crlf_crlf
    elif lf_lf in res_data:
        res_sep = lf_lf
    # for under HTTP/1.0 request type for servers doesn't support it
    #  and servers send just send body without header !
    if res_sep not in [crlf_crlf, lf_lf] or res_data.startswith('<'):
        return '', res_data
    # split header and data section from
    # `HEADER\r\n\r\nBODY` response or `HEADER\n\nBODY` response
    content = res_data.split(res_sep)
    banner, body = "".join(content[:1]), "".join(content[1:])
    return banner, body
```

Demo:

```
addresses = {'google.com': '216.239.32.20',
             'msdn.microsoft.com': '157.56.148.19',
}

for domain, ip in addresses.items():
    banner, body = http_banner_grabber(ip)
    print('*' * 24)
    print(domain, ip, 'HEAD HTTP/1.1')
    print(banner)
```

Also you can try it with `GET` method and also other options:

```
for domain, ip in addresses.items():
    banner, body = http_banner_grabber(ip, method="GET", http_type='HTTP/0.9')
    print('*' * 24)
    print(domain, ip, 'GET HTTP/0.9')
    print(banner)
```

Output (first example):

```
************************
google.com 216.239.32.20 HEAD HTTP/1.1
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 31 Mar 2014 01:25:53 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Set-Cookie: **** it was to long line and removed ****
P3P: **** it was to long line and removed ****
Server: gws
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Connection: close
************************
msdn.microsoft.com 157.56.148.19 HEAD HTTP/1.1
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Length: 0
Location: http://157.56.148.19/en-us/default.aspx
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
P3P: **** it was to long line and removed ****
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Instance: CH104
Date: Mon, 31 Mar 2014 01:25:53 GMT
Connection: close
```

Output (second example):

```
msdn.microsoft.com 157.56.148.19 GET HTTP/0.9
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Mon, 31 Mar 2014 01:27:13 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 311
************************
google.com 216.239.32.20 GET HTTP/0.9
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 1419
Date: Mon, 31 Mar 2014 01:27:14 GMT
Server: GFE/2.0
```

Now if you look at `Server` header of `msdn.microsoft.com` and `google.com` in two type of our example, through by this tool, we were able to discover a new thing:

- For `HTTP 1.1` request to `google.com`, `Server` is `gws` and for
  `HTTP 0.9` request, `Server` is changed to `GFE/2.0`.
- And for `HTTP 1.1` request to `msdn.microsoft.com`, `Server` is
  `Microsoft-IIS/8.0` and for `HTTP 0.9` request, `Server` is changed to 
  `Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0`.

Comment: it is probably simpler to make HEAD request using `httplib`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian,  Yes  it's also possible by using `httplib`, but `socket` is more conceptual. Thanks, your advices applied.

Comment: response may use `\n` instead `\r\n` (you should send `\r\n` but receive either `\r\n` or `\n`)