# Is it necessary to check both '\r\n\r\n' and '\n\n' as HTTP Header/Content separator?

Tags: http, http-headers

The accepted answer [on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22746480/banner-grabbing-http) says we should check HTTP server responses for both `\r\n\r\n` and `\n\n` as the sequence that separates the headers from the content.

Like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Ok\r\n
Server: AAA\r\n
Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n
Date: Fri, 07 Nov 2014 23:20:27 GMT\r\n
Content-Type: text/html\r\n
Connection: close\r\n\r\n   <--------------
```

or:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Ok\r\n
Server: AAA\r\n
Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n
Date: Fri, 07 Nov 2014 23:20:27 GMT\r\n
Content-Type: text/html\r\n
Connection: close\n\n   <--------------
```

In all the responses I've seen in Wireshark, servers use `\r\n\r\n`.

Is it really necessary to check for both? Which servers/protocol versions would use `\n\n`?

Answer (score 1):

I started off with `\r\n\r\n` but soon found some sites that used `\n\n`. And looking at some professional libraries like curl, they also handle `\n\n` even if it's not according to the standard.

I don't really know the curl code, but see for example here: https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/7a33c4dff985313f60f39fcde2f89d5aa43381c8/lib/http.c#L1406-L1413

```
/* find the end of the header line */
  end = strchr(start, '\r'); /* lines end with CRLF */
  if(!end) {
    /* in case there's a non-standard compliant line here */
    end = strchr(start, '\n');

    if(!end)
      /* hm, there's no line ending here, use the zero byte! */
      end = strchr(start, '\0');
  }
```

Looking at that I think even `\0\0` would be handled.

So:

- To handle "anything" out there, then yes.
- If you want to strictly follow the standard then no.

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html) says:

> The line terminator for message-header fields is the sequence CRLF. However, we recommend that applications, when parsing such headers, recognize a single LF as a line terminator and ignore the leading CR.

In practice I've never seen web server with CR line separator.